# How to animate properly in OpenFL

Tags: haxe, openfl

Currently I am trying to make an animation in OpenFL (without any frameworks), but i could not find any up-to-date tutorials and in the http://www.openfl.org/learn/tutorials/ you can only find tutorial written before the current version of OpenFl.

By "current version of OpenFL" I mean:
The new OpenFL  brings many changes, and perhaps one of the most important ones is the removal of **Tilesheet** class and the introduction of its new alternative - **Tilemap**.

Yet I didint lose hope and tried to figure it by fallowing this tutorial 
 http://haxecoder.com/post.php?id=25 and adjust my code to use **Tilemap** and **TileSet** and not **Tilesheet**

So in the end I managed to create a simple animation, but I dont think it is working properly / it is the proper way of doing it.

If there is someone who knows a place/link that shows how to animate properly or can help me by telling what I am doing wrong in the code bellow, I would be  eternally grateful.

the code:

```haxe
class Main extends Sprite {

    private var canvas:Sprite;
    private var tileset:Tileset;
    private var tilemap:Tilemap;

    private var steps:Array<Int>;

    private var stepCounter:Int = 0;
    private var currentX:Int = 5;
    private var currentY:Int = 5;
    private var firstFrame:Bool = true;

    public function new() {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e) {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        tileset = new Tileset(Assets.getBitmapData("img/Character.png"));

        steps = new Array<Int>();
        steps.push(tileset.addRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32)));
        steps.push(tileset.addRect(new Rectangle(32, 0, 32, 32)));
        steps.push(tileset.addRect(new Rectangle(64, 0, 32, 32)));

        tilemap = new Tilemap(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, tileset);
        canvas = new Sprite();

        canvas.addChild(tilemap);
        this.addChild(canvas);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, everyFrame);
    }


    private function everyFrame(e:Event):Void {
        var t:Tile = new Tile(stepCounter, ++currentX, ++currentY);
        if (++stepCounter > 3) stepCounter = 0;

        if (!firstFrame) {
            tilemap.removeTileAt(0);
        }

        firstFrame = false;
        tilemap.addTile(t);

        trace("tilemap.numTiles = " + tilemap.numTiles);
    }
}
```

the Character.png:
[image]

What Im unpleasant with (and it seems to me incorrect):
The way I update the animation 
i.e. on every frame creating a new **Tile** and removing the last in the **Tilemap**   `tilemap.removeTileAt(0);`

How it was handled in the previous OpenFl version:

```haxe
private var canvas:Sprite;
private var tilesheet:Tilesheet;
private var stepCounter = 0;

canvas = new Sprite();
addChild(canvas);
tilesheet = new Tilesheet(Assets.getBitmapData("img/set.png"));
tilesheet.addTileRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32));
tilesheet.addTileRect(new Rectangle(32, 0, 32, 32));
tilesheet.addTileRect(new Rectangle(64, 0, 32, 32));
```

and then simple add in the **Event.ENTER_FRAME** function:

```haxe
if (++stepCounter > 3) stepCounter = 0;
canvas.graphics.clear();
tilesheet.drawTiles(canvas.graphics, tileData);
```